# Using Ruby on Rails tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an html button in `html.erb` file. This button generates html controls and appends in table. It was working fine when there was no ruby on rails script involved. But now i have `select_tag` of RoR. This submits my page. My complete code as asked in comments is as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#AddSch").click(function() { 
            var hidval = $('#valEdu').val();
            if(hidval == 0)
            {
             hidval = 1;
            }
            else
            {
              //$('#valEdu').val(++hidval);
             hidval++;
            }  

            var rownum=$("#Controls > tbody > tr").length;
            var updated_row_num;
            if (rownum == 0)
            {
                updated_row_num=0;
            }
            else {
                updated_row_num=rownum/2;
            }
            var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>" + input1 + " <%= select_tag('university', options_from_collection_for_select(@Universites, 'id', 'University'),{:prompt => 'University'}) %></td></tr>";
            var control = "<tr><td align='center'><button type='button' class='btn_rmv'>Remove</button></td></tr>";

        $('#Controls').append(newRow);
        $('#Controls').append(control);
        return false;
      });

          $('#Controls').on('click', '.btn_rmv', function() {
                var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
                $('#Controls tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
                return false;
          });

    });
</script> 

<h2 class = "subtitle">
    Education
</h2>
<%= form_for (:Educations) do |f| %>
<table width="100%">
      <tr style = "text-align:center;">
         <td>
            <%= f.select :chapter,options_from_collection_for_select(@Chapters, "id", "Chapter"), :include_blank => "Chapter",:id => "DDL_Students",:style => "margin-top: 10px" %>

            <%= f.select :University,options_from_collection_for_select(@Universites, "id", "University"), :include_blank => "University",:id => "DDL_Students",:style => "margin-top: 10px" %>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <table id="Controls">
            </table>

            <div><input id="AddSch" value="Add" type="button" /></div>
            <input id="valEdu" type="hidden" value="0" />

         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table width="92%">
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <div class="button" style="margin-left:60px;">
                <%= f.submit "Next", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Removing `type="submit"` changes it to textbox and if I use `type="button"` it never calls that javascript. How can I make it work?

Comment: what is the full path/name of your javascript file? How are you making sure that the javascript file has Rails' helpers etc available to it, and that it can execute ERB?

Comment: The basic idea of executing some javascript when a type="button" input is clicked works fine - check out http://jsfiddle.net/a9kyu75r/

Comment: @joshua.paling i am using javascript in same page where i have placed add button i.e. new.html.erb. I have mentioned that this add button and click event are working fine. but it submits page when i placed this rails helper for select

Comment: Update your question to include the full code for your view, in a single code block.

Comment: @joshua.paling i have posted my complete code. and removed irrelevant segments. please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's two pointers that I can give you, I can't really reproduce as I dont have your model and controller action setup.

**1.** You do not want to randomly up or downcase your variables as in:

```
f.select :University,options_from_collection_for_select(@Universites, "id", "University"), :include_blank => "University",:id => "DDL_Students",:style => "margin-top: 10px"
```

Instead you want:

```
f.select :university, options_from_collection_for_select(@universities, "id", "university_name"), :include_blank => "University",:id => "DDL_Students",:style => "margin-top: 10px"
```

Ideally you wouldn't want the inline styles too, but we'll let that slip for now ;-)

**2.** I could the variable "input1" is not defined, have a look into your devtools console (F12) and check if there are any JS errors over there.

Hope that helps,
Jan

Comment: ok, i removed `var input1` part and forgot to remove it from code that i posted. I am following the same stuff as they are used in f.select and select_tag so this is not a problem too. anyways thanks for looking in